# How to merge an SBT-managed scala project with a Maven-managed Java project?

Tags: java, scala, maven, sbt

I have a legacy application that is written in Java and managed by Maven.

Recently I want to modify the code to make the application be able to run on a cluster of several machines. And I want to start with the akka-sample-cluster-scala template from activator, and the template is written in Scala and managed by SBT.

My question is: how can I merge the two projects together, so I can access my Java classes in the akka-sample-cluster-scala project or copy the code from akka-sample-cluster-scala project to my Java project and make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven and SBT have completely independent sets of plugins but use the same Maven Central repository to download dependencies and the same directory conventions.

To play with samples in Maven project I would try to configure [Scala Maven Plugin](https://github.com/davidB/scala-maven-plugin) in your Maven build. This seems to be simpler. However if you wish to use SBT you need to:

1. Create an SBT project
2. Place you Java code to **src/main/java** or copy the entire multi-module structure if this code has multiple modules.
3. Copy dependencies to SBT build files.
4. Find plugin equivalents for SBT if they exist and configure them in SBT. Seems to be tricky, though...

Comment: I tried this approach and it works, btw, I use the flowing script to convert the maven dependencies to sbt format, https://gist.github.com/retronym/388334, it makes the work  much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Make the Maven project a library dependency of the SBT project.

```
resolvers += Resolver.mavenLocal
libraryDependencies += "com.originjing" %% "legacy-app" & "1.0.0"
```

Comment: I tried the other approach and the resolvers += Resolver.mavenLocal solves part of the problem. Thank you.

Comment: @OriginJing once you get to 15 reputation, you can vote-up answers that you find useful.